# A personal project that one improves constantly

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

There's this phenomenon that occurs when one takes on a personal project, as a hobby, in a domain one is still learning. The project will progress, but then one will look back on what has already been done with the skills that have been gained in the meantime, see new ways to improve it, and scrape a good chunk of it to remake it better. Rinse and repeat.

I'm looking for an idiom, word or short phrase for such a project.

Things I have thought of :

- [Sisyphus' boulder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus): this one doesn't fit, because although the project could be seen as a neverending work loop that leads to no fruition, it remains a pleasant activity, not a punishment. The knowledge acquired through the iterations is also a net gain.
- [Pet project](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pet_project): this one comes close, but doesn't (as far as I know) convey the "endless remaking" part.

Comment: I think "pet project" or "hobby project" fit perfectly actually.

Comment: Sounds like the [Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus)

Comment: "Ship of theseus" and "Sisyphus's boulder" seem **way** too dramatic and pretentious for a hobby project.

Comment: In addition to *pet project*, which like @MaxWilliams I think is perfect, there's also *hobbyhorse*.

Comment: If I were more sure of my Latin, *eternum opus* would be my answer.

Comment: I’m not clear what you’re looking for here, so I’m not posting this as an answer, but the “endless remaking” part is conveyed by [perfect is the enemy of good](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good), a saying that refers to the fact that the relentless pursuit of perfection detracts and sidetracks resources that could be used to make progress toward an acceptable end product.

Answer (score 1):

"A perpetual work in progress" might be appropriate, implying that the work is never done and that the process is more important than the ultimate outcome.

Comment: It would be better if you could explain to us why that is a possible answer instead of asking "how about...?" :)

Comment: Duly edited. I am a newbie, so the criticism is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Practice project.

This is something that you can mess up on as you're learning.  It's not intended for public consumption.

(But "pet project" might actually be better.)

Answer (score 0):

"Continual improvement" is a common term, a key aspect of which is the conduct of "after-action reviews (AARs)." AARs focus on what went well and what could have gone better. The latter result in the conscious identification and pursuit of "opportunities for improvement."

Comment: Do you have sources to support your claim, especially regarding a personal project? It seems like more of a corporate thing to say. Have a look at the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good answers

Comment: This is a perfectly good -- and direct --answer. You could view it as a "corporate thing," but so what if it is, even if it started out that way? Continual improvement applies on any scale, corporate to individual. Also, the questioner referred to project, but as an example he used hobby. A hobby is an ongoing activity, not a project; the latter is typically time bound, like cleaning up the basement. A hobby could be learning to paint, golf, gardening, birding, whatever. I'm sure you could ground truth my "claim" by googling it, but it's not like it's a foreign or counterintuitive term.

Answer (score 0):

Program-wise, especially regarding games, this is often referred to as a "Perpetual Beta". I hate to keep you busy for the rest of your free time, but I think [the TV Tropes page on the subject](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PerpetualBeta) would explain it better than I could here.

Comment: I'm aware that "Beta" often implies it to be unfinished, but many designers will refer to their project as such until they abandon it, so sometimes a program _not_ being listed as beta can be a death sentence to any new features. Though, for the linked example, you'd have to scroll down into the "Real Life examples" section to find this reasoning...

Answer (score 0):

I like "one step forward two steps back" to use if you wanted to describe a situation where the more you learn, the more you realize you have left to learn.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/One+step+forward,+two+steps+back